# Ember JS not inserting data from API into the template

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js

I have just started with ember and am slowly getting my head round it. This is most likely an incredibly easy question to answer but i've been trying to find an answer for ages now and have had no luck. I am using ember-tools and have hooked up my ember app with my Laravel API successfully. I use Fractal as the transformer for the API and am using the JsonAPISerializer which I believe is the correct format for Ember (take a look [here](http://fractal.thephpleague.com/serializers/)). I have just been trying to plug in data from a user record into the template to get going.

Here's the JSON returned:

```
{  
"user":[  
  {  
     "id":1,
     "firstName":"Jacob",
     "surname":"Windsor",
     "country":"",
     "city":"",
     "pro":false,
     "emailSubscribed":false,
     "emailConfirmed":false,
     "artist":true,
     "blogger":false,
     "avatar":false,
  }
]
}
```

This is the route I have defined:

```
this.resource('user', {path: '/user/:user_id'});
```

And in `user_route.js`:

```
var UserRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params){
        return App.User.find(params.user_id);
    }
});

module.exports = UserRoute;
```

The `user.js` model:

```
var attr = DS.attr;
var User = DS.Model.extend({
    firstName: attr('string'),
    surname: attr('string'),
    country: attr('string'),
    city: attr('string'),
    pro: attr('boolean'),
    emailSubscribed: attr('boolean'),
    emailConfirmed: attr('boolean'),
    artist: attr('boolean'),
    blogger: attr('boolean'),
    avatar: attr('boolean'),
```

});

module.exports = User;

And finally the handlebars template:

```
<h2>user</h2>
{{firstName}}
```

No errors appear in the console and the resource is retrieved from the API if I navigate to `/#/user/1`. I thought maybe I had got something wrong with naming conventions but then maybe the resource wouldn't be retrieved from the API at all. If any more information is required to help me out on this please say.

### Update 1

In ember inspector, if I click on the user model (`<App.User:ember333:1>`) it comes up with the model data but it is not populated from the API response. So all string values are empty and all booleans false but the ID is correct so I assume ember has retrieved it from the URL.

### Update 2

I have updated my model code to this:

```
var UserRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params){
        return this.store.find('user',params.user_id).then(function(){
            alert('working!');
        }, function(){
            alert(':(');
        });
    }
});
```

It does show as working so the API is being hit correctly it would seem.

Comment: Which version of ember-data you are using? If it's the latest beta8 try to use `this.store.find('user',params.user_id')` in your model, the one you are using is the old API. For more information on the API changes check this https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md. Hope it helps

Comment: @Altrim No error is thrown when using that but it still does the same thing.

Comment: Do you have installed Ember Inspector https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ember-inspector/bmdblncegkenkacieihfhpjfppoconhi?hl=en ? Check in the inspector if the correct route is called. And do you have a resolved model when entering the route.

Comment: @Altrim Please look at my update. What do you mean by resolved model?

Comment: I assume since you get there empty values when you print `firstName` you get nothing (e.g if you print one of the boolean attributes you will get false). I would say check again if you return the correct information from the API. Or create a jsbin.

Comment: I just noticed the returned JSON you are returning an array of user objects. Try to return just the user object from the API. Maybe that causes the issue

Comment: I thought it might be something like that. However, because I am using Fractal it is difficult to change it without affecting other resources. Please look at this http://fractal.thephpleague.com/resources/

Comment: Hmm I've never used fractal, but I guess that's the default that it returns. Maybe try to normalize the data http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#method_normalize